# How to align the widgets to the right in single column?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want the widgets to align right but a single column used. Is there another way to align these items?

Code:

```
Column(LayoutPadding(20.dp)) {
    Align(alignment = Alignment.TopRight) {
        Text(text = "0")
        Text(text = "testOperation")
    }
}
```

Result:

```
(RIGHT ALIGNED) 0
```

Expected:

```
(RIGHT ALIGNED) 0 
(RIGHT ALIGNED) testOperation
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this,

```
        Align(alignment = Alignment.TopRight) {
            Column(LayoutPadding(20.dp)){
                Text(text = "0")
                Text(text = "testOperation")
            }
        }
```

Or like this, depending on your usage.

```
    Column(LayoutPadding(20.dp)) {
        Align(alignment = Alignment.TopRight) {
            Column(){
                Text(text = "0")
                Text(text = "testOperation")
            }
        }
    }
```

You can align each Text using Alignment.TopRight, BottomRight and so on.

```
Column(LayoutPadding(20.dp)) {
    Column(){
        Text(text = "0")
        Align(alignment = Alignment.TopRight) {
            Text(text = "testOperation")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the first text x-axis based on 2nd text. how can the first text stay on the right?

Comment: How about this ?
`Column(LayoutPadding(20.dp)) {
                Column(){
                    Text(text = "0")
                    Align(alignment = Alignment.TopRight) {
                        Text(text = "testOperation")
                    }
                }
            } `

Comment: It did not arrive at the expected answer. Do you have other layouts that make these two texts on the right?

Comment: Yes, how about Container? Or may be Card Layout can help you.

Answer (score 0):

With `1.0.0-beta03` just use something like:

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
) {
    Column (){
        Text(
                text = "First item",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
        Text(
                text = "Second item",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
        Text(
                text = "Third item",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]